# Open webpage in existing window of Chromium from command line

Tags: debian, chrome

Is this the way to make Chromium change web page while it is already running from the command line without opening an additional browser window?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default current Chromium (and Chrome) releases open webpages in a new tab in the last interacted-with window.

So `Chromium www.google.com` will open in a new tab and not in a new window.

If your Chromium does that, it might be really old (as in more than 3 years old), or perhaps you have an extension that forces new windows?

If you by chance actually meant you wanted it to open in a new window, try `Chromium --new-window www.google.com`.

If it still doesn't work, try to start Chromium with the `--disable-extensions` flag and otherwise update the question with the specific command you're using.